# Нативный аналог jquery.index() и jquery.eq()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Или направьте меня хотя бы как сделать нечто подобное. На входе у меня Event (практически произвольный) и его event.target, на выходе нужно воспроизвести этот евент максимально точно, в промежутке нужно сохранить данные в максимально сжатом размере. Буду рад любым идеям. Я написал один вариант с использованием вышеупомянутых jquery index на входе и eq на выходе, но мне крайне желательно избавиться от jquery

**UP:**
Не знаю почему я сразу код не добавил, думал и так ясно.. вот:

```
//На входе
app.element_to_event=function(el,old){
    var selector=null;
    if(old.id || el.id){
        selector='#'+old.id || el.id;//Одинаковые id = баг
    }else{
        if(old.class || el.className){
            selector='.'+(old.class || el.className).split(' ').join('.');
        }else{
            selector=el.tagName;
            if(el.name){
                selector+='[name='+el.name+']';
            }
        }
    }
    if(!selector)console.warn('No selector!',el,old);
    return {
        selector: selector,
        index: $(selector).index(el)
    }
}


//На выходе
var el=self.view.find(data[i].selector).eq(data[i].index);
```

Comment: Покажите, что уже написали. А то непонятно, где и что улучшать.

Comment: Вообще если вы модифицируете DOM между вашими «входом» и «выходом», то у вас индексы могут поплыть.

Comment: у меня точный клон страницы. Делаю нечто наподобие вебвизора в яндекс метрике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выбора элементов по селектору в чистом DOM можно пользоваться [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

```
var nodeList = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

Теперь в `nodeList` список элементов внутри `parent`, удовлетворяющих селектору. Достать элемент по номеру просто:

```
var element = nodeList[index];
```

Найти номер по элементу можно, например, так:

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodeList, element);
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Я,собственно, пытался так сделать, но index пробовал так - nodelist.indexOf(element), и это не заработало.

Comment: в этом случае вы можете использовать синтаксис Javascript: `nodelist[index]`