# Как определить индекс удаленного элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448256/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-jquery-index-%D0%B8-jquery-eq/448344#448344).

Есть две абсолютно идентичные страницы. Моя задача - чтобы они оставались идентичными. Проблема возникает, когда есть набор элементов с одинаковыми селекторами, и один из них удаляется. Не пойму, как понять, какой именно. Вот выжимка из кода -

```js
function build_selector(el){
 var selector=null;
 if(el.id){
  selector='#'+el.id;
 }else{
  if(el.className){
   selector='.'+el.className.split(' ').join('.');
  }else{
   selector=el.tagName;
   if(el.name){
    selector+='[name='+el.name+']';
   }
  }
 }
 if(!selector)console.error('Cant build selector!',el);
 var index=$(selector).index(el);//Т.к. элемента уже нет в DOM, индекс == -1
 if(index==-1)console.error('Smth wrong with:',selector,el);
 return {
  selector: selector,
  index: index
 }
}

var target = document.querySelector('html');
observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
  var target=build_selector(mutation.target);
  target.removed=[];
  for(var i=0;i<mutation.removedNodes;i++){

   target.removed.push(build_selector(mutation.removedNodes[i]));
  }
 });
});
observer.observe(target, {
 childList: true,
 subtree: true
});


//test
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.some_class').eq(2).remove();
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="some_class">1</span>
<span class="some_class">2</span>
<span class="some_class">3</span>
<span class="some_class">4</span>
<span class="some_class">5</span>
```

Вот так я удаляю элементы в клоне (View - корневой элемент, data[i] - это target из сниппета):

```
var el=View.find(data[i].selector).eq(data[i].index);
for(var j=0;j<data[i].removed.length;j++){
   el.find(data[i].removed[j].selector).eq(data[i].removed[j].index).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно получить уникальный селектор для элемента, добавьте в свой код на этапе матчинга класса, нечто подобное:

```
  var siblings = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.parentNode.childNodes, 0);

  var index = siblings.indexOf(el) + 1;

  if (index > 1) {
    selector += ':nth-child(' + index + ')';
  }
```

Что добавит уникальности селектору.

Но что касается в целом решаемой вами задачи, если она мною верно понята, вам стоит посмотреть на:

1. https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom
2. https://github.com/fouber/page-monitor
3. https://github.com/tbranyen/diffhtml